# Link helper to action of all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Today I realized,that I have such links in 5 different views

```
<%= link_to t(:edit, scope: [:admin, :actions :model_name]), edit_admin_model_name_path(model_name)), class: "icon-edit" %>
<%= link_to t(:delete, scope: [:admin, :actions :model_name]), admin_model_name_path(model_name)),method: :delete, class: "icon-edit", data: { confirm: t(:confirm, scope: [:admin, :confirmation, eval(":#{model}s")]) %>
```

and my code looks really awful. So I want to create a helper method for such links. I think, it should looks like this:

```
  def link_to_edit(model)
    link_to t(:edit, scope: [:admin, :actions :model_name]), edit_admin_METHOD_I_NEED(model)_path(METHOD_I_NEED(model)), class: "icon-edit"
  end
  def link_to_delete(model)
    link_to t(:delete, scope: [:admin, :actions :model_name]), admin_METHOD_I_NEED(model)_path(METHOD_I_NEED(model))), method: :delete, class: "icon-delete", data: { confirm: t(:confirm, scope: [:admin, :confirmation, ":#{model}s"]) }
  end
```

So, what I need is ruby method opposite to `#{}`.

Do Ruby have such method or should I do this in other way?

**ANSWER:**

I combined two answers:

```
def link_to_delete(model) 
  link_to t(:delete, scope: [:admin, :actions, model.pluralize.to_sym]), url_for(controller: model.pluralize.to_sym,...), method: :delete, class: "icon-delete", data: { confirm: t(:confirm, scope: [:admin, :confirmation, model.pluralize.to_sym) } 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `model.pluralize.to_sym` instead of `":#{model}s"`.

Example:

```
1.9.2-p290 :005 > "person".pluralize.to_sym
 => :people
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `url_for` is what you want.

Take a look:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor/url_for